# How to convert multiple single-end bam files to fastq using samtools

Tags: sam, samtools, fastq, format-conversion

Hi I am trying to convert `bam` files generated from Ion Torrent Proton sequencing to `fastq` format so that I can upload them to KBase for analysis.

The files are named as follows:
`01_thu159_IX_RNA_001.bam 01_thu163_IX_RNA_001.bam 01_thu164_IX_RNA_001.bam 01_thu190_IX_RNA_001.bam`

So I tried:

`samtools fastq *.bam > *.fastq`

However, that did not work. But, I know it is possible to use a placeholder for the name in code by using something like `$f` or I have also seen `%N%`. I am just not sure how to basically use those placeholders to be able to quickly apply a `for` loop, which will convert the files to fastq format without having to do each one individually. I have 28 samples each containing 4 `bam` files. Any advice on how I can do this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with `samtools` however your example, which I believe is run through the terminal, is printing all the output into a single file and not into many, as you may think. I guess that by using `> *.fastq` you meant to create many fastq files, which is not what you're doing.
also I found this link that may help you https://onestopdataanalysis.com/bam-to-fastq/ and here it looks like they process one file at a time. if this is the case you just need a `for loop` to run the command for each file

Comment: Hi there, yes I was running that command in the terminal. So the idea basically was I don't want to have to type the name of the individual files in each case. For example I would like to know how to write the ```for loop``` so that it converts the ```bam``` file to ```fastq``` format and maintains the same file name just the format is changed. Otherwise I will have to type out each name individually as such: ```samtools fastq 01_thu159_IX_RNA_001.bam > 01_thu159_IX_RNA_001.fastq``` and this is tedious considering how many files I have.

Comment: ok, so your question actually was about how to run a command on multiple files at once, am I right? If yes, then here you can find some answers to that specific question:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80851/how-do-i-run-a-command-on-multiple-files
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80851/how-do-i-run-a-command-on-multiple-files

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Thank you, I truly appreciate the assistance.

Comment: of course, if you are not able to write the necessary code, you can still ask a question regarding that specific point. However, I believe there should be enough information in the two answers I linked to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU parallel:

```
ls *.bam | parallel -j 2 "samtools fastq {} > {.}.fastq"
```

Use `-j` to control the number of parallel jobs. That only works for single-end data though as paired-end data must first be sorted or collated by name.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate it. My data is single-end reads, as it was generated using Ion Torrent, so this should work well.

Comment: @Justin1609 Yes, I guess that should work with the above command without problems.